Linear transformation $T\colon P_3(\Bbb R)\to P_3(\Bbb R)$
I have a linear transformation $T\colon P_3(\mathbb{R}) \to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ where
$$T(p(x)) = \frac{\mathrm p(x)}{\mathrm dx} + p(x)$$
I want to find the image of  $T(3x^2+4x+3)$.
However I'm not sure if i can do the transformation because the question is in quadratic polynomial. I know that it can be seen as quartic polynomials with the quartic coefficient is zero. But does that count as $P_3(\mathbb{R})$?
Note: $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is vector space of all polynomial at degree at least $3$.

You should define $P_3(\mathbb R)$

Yes, check definition in your textbook.  How is $P_3(\mathbb R)$ defined there?  Personally, I would define it so that $P_3(\mathbb R)$ includes $P_2(\mathbb R)$.

Are you sure its polynomials of degree at least $3$, not at most $3$?

Just apply the linearity of the derivative:
\begin{align*}
T(3x^{2} + 4x + 3) & = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(3x^{2} + 4x + 3) + 3x^{2} + 4x + 3\\\\
& = 6x + 4 + 0 + 3x^{2} + 4x + 3\\\\
& = 3x^{2} + 10x + 7
\end{align*}

So the question is still in the domain?

@Ocean I suppose $\mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ means the vector space of all polynomials with degree less than or equal to three. What are you particularly struggling with?

Oh thank you so much. At first i thought it means polynomial with degree of three

@Ocean You are welcome! I am glad to help.

Note: $3x^2+4x+3=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, thus $3x^2+4x+3\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$

Alternatively, you can consider the basis first (this might be useful if you have to compute multiple transformations), that is $[x^3,x^2,x,1]$.
$$T(1)=1,T(x)=x+1,T(x^2)=x^2+2x,T(x^3)=x^3+3x^2$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}T(3x^2+4x+3)&=0T(x^3)+3T(x^2)+4T(x)+3T(1)\\
&=0\cdot(x^3+3x^2)+3(x^2+2x)+4(x+1)+3\cdot1\\
&=3x^2+10x+7\in P_3(\mathbb{R})
\end{align}$$
